# Checking for incoming connections to ServerSocket

Tags: java, tcp

Is there a way to check for incoming connections to ServerSocket, so my server would not stop when waiting for someone to connect.

I need something like

```
try {
if (server.thereisarequest()) {
Socket socket = server.accept();
}
}
```

Comment: Why? Just run a normal accept loop in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want this? Having the code presented, only one thread is waiting. Run another threads which handle accepted connections so that your server doesn't stop. 
You can also use java non-blocking asynchronous I/O (nio and nio2), but in the background there is a thread on duty anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple... use an **infinite** `while` **loop to make server look for the incoming request**... thats how most of the servers works..

```
while (true) {

incoming = s.accept();  // incoming is of type Socket.                              

}
```

Comment: and the program will go forward or it will stop and wait for the request?

Comment: It keeps on waiting for the request..... `Now you need to put that client object obtained from s.accept() into another separate thread to process, while server keeps waiting for another client...`

Comment: it keeps on waiting for request, but the server is still working? I mean it would still print text on every frame while waiting for the incoming request?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new thread to accept connections.

Then you have 2 choices:

- Process the socket in a new thread
- Put the sockets in a queue (`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`) and check it queue from you main thread.